# C# 6 null propagation what value is set when object is null

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

```
var result = myObject?.GetType();
```

In this scenario what would be the value of Result if `myObject` is null?

Comment: Take a look at my article on [What's New in C# 6](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/whats-new-in-c-6/). There I show what's happening behind the curtain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your object does not hide default `object.GetType` definition: `GetType` returns `Type`, which is a reference type, so `null` will be returned, and `result` will be inferred to be of type `Type`.

If your object has a method which does hide `object.GetType`, it will also return `null`, but type inferred for `result` might change: it will either be `TResult` if that method returns reference type `TResult`, or `Nullable<TResult>` if it returns a value type of type `TResult`.

Answer (score 6):

The result should be `null` because the `?` operator short circuits the operation.